# how to reopen modal dialog in jquery after closing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Asp.Net MVC application, where in 1 View, I have a list with every record showing Edit icon. Clicking the edit icon opens a modal dialog popup to update the record .

I face problem in reopening the dialog or clicking other edit icon for popup after closing the dialog . 
        Following is my jquery code to open the dialog :

```
var singltym;

$(function () {

    $('#addSingleTimeDialog').dialog({
            cache: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 450,
            height: 450,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            resizable: true,
            modal: true});

    $('#singletymlink').on('click', function () {
            singltym = $(this);
            var dialogDiv = $('#addSingleTimeDialog');
            var viewUrl = singltym.attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: viewUrl,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    dialogDiv.html(data);
                    dialogDiv.dialog('open');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: Please post your full code (<div>) in the question because I find the solution for you problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    var singltym;

    $(function () {

        $('#addSingleTimeDialog').dialog({
                cache: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 450,
                height: 450,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                resizable: true,
                modal: true});

        $('#singletymlink').on('click', function () {
                singltym = $(this);
                var dialogDiv = $('#addSingleTimeDialog');
                var viewUrl = singltym.attr('href');
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    url: viewUrl,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (data) {
                        dialogDiv.html(data);
                       dialogDiv.dialog('open');
```

//I work in this method

```
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                }
            });
        });
});
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    url: viewUrl,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (data) {
                        dialogDiv.html(data);
                       $("#dialogDiv").dialog("open");

                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                }
```

If `$( this ).dialog( "close" );` not working because not try this specific sentence??

```
$('#addSingleTimeDialog').dialog("close");
```

Comment: I even tried intercepting the script with `$( this ).dialog( "close" );` , but no success.

Comment: and ´$('#addSingleTimeDialog').dialog("close");´ you tried?? @ShalinJirawla

Comment: ya even tried `$('#addSingleTimeDialog').dialog("close");` , but to no success

Comment: Please copy your code and paste on http://jsfiddle.net/ because miss the code in html (div)

Comment: thanx @Mirko for your help in solving the above issue

Comment: $( this ).dialog( "close" ); WORKED PERFECTLY. (y)

Answer (score 3):

The above issue can be solved by including the below scripts in parent view from where the dialog popup is clicked & initiated :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

As well as insert the below scripts in child view which is the UI for modal dialog popup :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

By scripting in such way, the jquery script conflict is avoided & reopening of dialog can be swiftly done.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`open`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open) method:

```
$('#addSingleTimeDialog').dialog('open');
```

Comment: I know I can, but I have to load the dialog with dynamic data  which comes from server side controller action, for which I need to build the dialog with url & pass the data as html for the dialog UI

Comment: The strange thing is that the same script I am using in other view, & it is working fine. I analysed & found that it is not refreshing the dialog. I did the following to forcibly refresh it .

`$('#updateMstrTaskDialog').dialog({
        cache: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 300,
        height: 230,
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        close: function () {
            location.reload();
        }
    });`
It works but with an unwanted postback.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this older question, found a simpler solution not listed here.

Add an event listener for the close event, and call destroy when the dialog is closed.

```
close: function(event, ui) {$(this).dialog("destroy");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing `$( this ).dialog( "close" );` method in close function. Eg :

```
close: function(){ $( this ).dialog( "close" ); },
```

`$( this ).dialog( "close" );` does not destroy the dialog, instead it just closes and makes it available to be used for next time.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by replacing

```
$(this).dialog("close");
```

with

```
$(this).dialog("destroy");
```